# TRIM / STR text from a certain symbol

Tags: php, trim

I have this code:

```
$title = &$cleantitle;
$cleantitle = str_replace(' ', '', $cleantitle);
```

`$title` =  `./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/January/January - Intro Video/V001-Test-Video.mp4`

I would like the get

`$cleantitle` = `V001-Test-Video`

I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

Comment: @Rizier123, Hello, does that also remove the first part. looking into it.

Comment: Yes. Just use `pathinfo()` and get the filename

Comment: @Rizier123 - Thank you as always

Comment: The solution: `$title=$files[$file]; 
$cleantitle = basename($title, ".mp4");`